# Multiple row update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am having a problem updating several rows of a mysql table using a single mysql statement.

I have the rowids i want to update in a string eg.

```
$ids="id1, id2, id3, id4,...."
```

and i have my values in another string eg.

```
$values="str1, str2, str3, str4,....";
```

(i have more than 30,000 rows to update)

The idea is the row with id1 should be updated with str1 and so on.

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: explode this 2 strings to arrays and with foreach loop , update the db

Comment: i have more than 30,000 rows to update.... this means running more than 30,000 queries. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You should definitely do a batch update. But I dont know how. May be you can use LOAD DATA and UPDATE ON DUPLICATE. But that will require research and testing.

Comment: 30,000 rows shouldn't be THAT bad if you group them into transactions (i.e. don't do a commit for each statement, do a commit every 100 inserts or something).  Assuming you are using InnoDB here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a very ugly query but...

```
update table
set    str = case id
             when id1 then str1
             when id2 then str2
             ...
             end
where  id in (id1, id2, ...)
```

Comment: Assemble this query as a string - in a for-loop and the run the query once.

Comment: I'm wondering how MySQL will cope with a query that long, though. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table with two columns, id and str, and do a very long

```
INSERT INTO temptable VALUES (id1,str1),(id2,str2)...(idn,strn);
```

You build the string in a for loop *without* going to the DB. Then you do one `UPDATE` joining to the temp table in the obvious way. (Indexing the temp table may or may not help.)

You don't want 30K round trips to the DB. (On the other hand, you may have to split the `INSERT` up if you run into maximum string length issues.)